# Google Account API basic login

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-signin

I work at a performance agency and we have an agency account at Google Analytics. This account, have permissions to read or edit GA accounts of our clients.

For our agency account we ask for the API (https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1qfRFysCikpgCMGqgF3yXdUyQW4xAlLyjKuOoOEFN2Uw/viewform) and receive it.

But with this API we cannot download basic items as visits, time of visit, bounce-rate, conversions...

Please can you recommend us any technique to receive all data from GA of our clients? We need to use to login our agency account (not logins of clients).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong API. The [Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) reports hits from the last 30 minutes; it cannot report aggregated values (so no session- or user scoped metrics and dimensions). Realtime API is e.g. used for monitoring and getting alerts for sudden changes, it's not necessarily useful for reporting.

You should be looking at the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) instead which will give you the data you want, but does not work in realtime; it requires up to 24 hours processing time before fully processed data is available.

For the login you need to have your agency account added to each GA account yoz want to query. If you want to login programmatically (i.e. from a script without opening a browser) you should create a [service account](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/authorization#service_accounts) and ask your clients to add this to all GA accounts you want to query.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.

I understand all, but "service account" is problem. Because there is a problem to hace two accouta who is lookig to client accout. Is possible to have agency and service account in one? So "agency account" = "service account".